# Vue JS Function not returning an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a property initialized in my data model as such:

```
someArray: []
```

I have an array from a function here:

```
getMyArray: function (someId) {
                var result = [7, 8, 9, 10];
                return result;
}
```

I'm calling the function here:

```
this.someArray = this.getMyArray(value);
```

My property `someArray` isn't getting the desired result. It's returning a single empty item.

I heard somewhere that I may have to push each item manually instead. Is this true? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Full example...

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '[some-app]',
    data: {
        someArray: []
    },
    methods: {
        getMyArray: function (someId) {
                var result = [7, 8, 9, 10];
                return result;
            });
        },
    },
    watch: {
        someChangingId: function (value) {
            this.someArray = this.getMyArray(value);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: where in the code are you asigning  this.someArray = this.myArray(someValue); ?

Comment: can you show the whole component? Are you trying to use a computed property?

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, objects and arrays are references, different from other variable types.

Your could go for:

```
myArray: function (value) {
  var result = new Array(4);
  result[0] = 7;
  result[1] = 8;
  result[2] = 9;
  result[3] = 10;
  return result;
}
```

And then use the `.slice()` method which will correctly copy the array:

```
this.someArray = this.myArray('someValue').slice();
```

By the way, I do not understand why you are passing the `value` parameter, as it is not being used in your function.

Comment: That is not necessary. The only [change detection caveat](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in Vue.js is property addition or deletion.